# A list of philosophic schools

Tags: reference-request

I want to learn more about philosophy, but I don't know much about the different philosophic schools yet and I don't want to waste my time, so I want to know if there is an exhaustive list of philosophic schools with a sort description of its fundamentals.

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Comment: @JosephWeissman I have read some basic philosophy; the ideas of Plato, Aristoteles, Nietzsche, Locke, Hume,  Descartes, etc. But I don't know much about different philosophic schools and I want to study interesting schools extensively, I however, because of work and studies, haven't got much time to look into a lot of schools, I just want a list of schools and their central ideas and such.

Comment: I meant more what resources you might already have come across; e.g., http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_movement

Comment: @ZafarS: why are you interested in philosophy, if thats not too impudent a question. What sort of questions interest you? ethical, political, scientific etc.

Comment: @MoziburUllah It's certainly not too impudent. I am a scientific man myself, so that's important. What I like about philosophy is being able to relate to people who have the same mindset and ideas, and perhaps even learn about a certain philosophy I totally disagree with. It gives me a new view on the world and helps me relate to other people.

Comment: @JosephWeissman I have come across a couple of list like the one you linked, but I want something more concise in its description of the movements.

Comment: @ZafarS: Well, the epicurean school with its emphasis on the atomistic/materialistic might be a nice point to start with; The relevant portions of Lucretious de Rerum Natura is suprisingly, in just how far they went in deducing 19C physics; they also postulate a fundamental unpredictability, which again is surprising considering just how taken aback 20C physicists were when Heisenberg presented his uncertainty principle

Comment: @ZafarS: The opposite point of view to the scientific, would be idealism; it postulates all is mental/mind. The Neoplatonists might be a good start. Perhaps, also the Lokyata-Nyaya school of Indian materialism/logic might be useful.

Comment: I am not aware of anyone who categorizes philosophy or philosophy of the last 200 years into schools. There would be extremely many schools on the list, and they would be contested categories, as philosophers themselves do not identify with "schools." Regardless, except to approach the philosophy of very specific times, places, and topics (e.g. 3rd century Alexandrian cosmology), this is not a productive way to learn about philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

To be perfectly honest, your question's a little offensive. I could equally well ask you: where can I find an exhaustive list of the different sciences that exist? How would such a question be reasonably answered? Not to mention that "schools of thought" are so varied that its unclear what you really mean by it. To be charitable, I'll assume that you're looking for the *branches* of philosophy, which is answerable.

All that said, it's still useful to know what the broad strokes of philosophy are, and for that there's a recent, decent **[book by Simon Blackburn](http://books.google.de/books/about/Think.html?id=Z8_ecemnfvsC)** you could read through in few hours. In it, he teases out eight major branches of philosophy which cover most of the spectrum. I've rewritten his chapter titles to be more specific.

#### Epistemology

What do we know, and how can we know it? What is the nature of knowledge? What's the difference between true statements such as "3 + 2 = 5" and "The Statue of Liberty stands on Liberty Island"?

#### Consciousness

What is the phenomenon of being awake and aware? How is it different or similar to dreaming? What is pain? Is it possible to be certain that anyone else suffers the same phenomena I do?

#### Freedom

If the ability exists for all actions to be predicted, what does it mean to say that I am the agent responsible for my own actions? Is it meaningful at all, or just a hallucination?

#### Identity

Are you the same person you were yesterday? Will you be the same person fifty years from now? If I take some other object, and replace its parts one at a time, at what point does it ever cease to be the same object?

#### Ontology

Is there a Creator? If not, how did the the world (i.e., the universe) come to exist in the first place? Is causality a real relationship between events or just one we impose on the universe to make it sensible? Where do our beliefs about these things come from?

#### Logic

What is the difference between a good and a bad argument? What series of rules will always produce correct results? How can we describe the things we say or write in a way that allows them to be evaluated by these rules? What beliefs can we evaluate in this way?

#### Perception

Are the qualities of objects in the world produced by those objects, or are they imposed on those objects by our mind? By what means can we judge the things we see, hear, smell, etc., to be facts about the world and not imaginative hallucinations or clever illusions?

#### Ethics

Are beliefs sufficient to motivate certain actions? What are those qualities of an event, object, or person which makes it *good*?

---

There's more, of course. Blackburn leaves out much about Aesthetics and other value judgement theories. For instance, Rational Choice theory - which belongs under Ethics, but drifts into discussions of economics and ultimately game theory. Emotions are a topic unto themselves, but bridge Consciousness, Epistemology, and Perception. Metaphysics is an entirely other topic, with ties to epistemology and ontology, but asks questions like "must possible worlds exist?".

Blackburn's book will at least help introduce the eight topics above in a way that lets you distinguish what areas you actually might have an interest in, and whether to branch into any of these others I've just mentioned.

**If** however this all leaves you dissatisfied, I can only direct you to the table of contents at **[PhilPapers](http://philpapers.org)** which has a nice list of topics and the number of papers their database holds on each. The length, I hope, will demonstrate why an explicit list isn't really something you're going to find - unless you write one yourself. Here's a snapshot (number of papers in parentheses):

**Metaphysics and Epistemology (87,829)**
Epistemology (12,856)
Metaphilosophy (1,684)
Metaphysics (12,849)
Philosophy of Action (8,325)
Philosophy of Language (16,190)
Philosophy of Mind (23,776)
Philosophy of Religion (12,088)
M&E, Misc (55)

**Value Theory (129,559)**
Aesthetics (16,341)
Applied Ethics (46,701)
Meta-Ethics (4,440)
Normative Ethics (8,927)
Philosophy of Gender, Race, and Sexuality (6,109)
Philosophy of Law (4,738)
Social and Political Philosophy (30,376)
Value Theory, Miscellaneous (2,038)

**Science, Logic, and Mathematics (82,415)**
Logic and Philosophy of Logic (13,726)
Philosophy of Biology (8,802)
Philosophy of Cognitive Science (18,426)
Philosophy of Computing and Information (981)
Philosophy of Mathematics (3,080)
Philosophy of Physical Science (5,346)
Philosophy of Social Science (12,170)
Philosophy of Probability (1,892)
General Philosophy of Science (5,776)
Philosophy of Science, Misc (945)

**History of Western Philosophy (97,540)**
Ancient Greek and Roman Philosophy (30,155)
Medieval and Renaissance Philosophy (6,386)
17th/18th Century Philosophy (19,733)
19th Century Philosophy (11,737)
20th Century Philosophy (25,892)
History of Western Philosophy, Misc (112)

**Philosophical Traditions (21,011)**
African/Africana Philosophy (671)
Asian Philosophy (9,105)
Continental Philosophy (3,419)
European Philosophy (3,681)
Philosophy of the Americas (1,988)
Philosophical Traditions, Miscellaneous (937)

**Philosophy, Misc (1,116)**
Philosophy, Introductions and Anthologies (28)
Philosophy, General Works (837)
Philosophy, Miscellaneous (213)

**Other Academic Areas (21,285)**
Natural Sciences (88)
Social Sciences (371)
Cognitive Sciences (458)
Formal Sciences (406)
Arts and Humanities (19,595)
Professional Areas (147)
Other Academic Areas, Misc (60)

Comment: I don't consider it offensive, I wouldn't be offended if you told me you want a list of the different sciences. Also, you shouldn't compare sciences (multiple field, with multiple 'subfields')to philosophy (one field, multiple 'subfields'). Also, this doesn't answer my question, I didn't ask for branches of philosophy, I asked for philosophical schools. I don't get why this has 5 upvotes, it's a good answer to a different question, not to mine.

Comment: Then pray tell, what do you mean by "schools"?

Comment: The point is that it's an impossibly broad question, and you want to someone here to help you narrow the focus of your search. Philosophy is more easily identified by topic first, and only then does it become sensible to start asking "what schools of thought" there are on a given topic.

Comment: As for "offensive" I was referring to the way you characterized a task that people spend their lives doing -studying the history of philosophy and the taxonomy of 3,000 years of argumentation- as a "waste of your time".

Comment: @Ryder That was an unfortunate choice of words on John's part, but I don't think that is what was intended.  I think it is reasonable to choose to interpret his words as "I know so little about philosophy, that I have a feeling that I would reinvent the wheel if I were to try to start without some sort of map."  I know I've wanted to beat my head into a desk many a time when I programmed up some wizz-bang program over the course of 2 weeks, just to find out that someone had already made it and released it as open source!

Comment: @JohnPhteven And to try to read between the lines of Ryder's post, the fact that he chose to interpret your question the way he did suggests that it is very natural for him to organize philosophy in that fashion.  You might consider this your first bit of philosophical feedback from this question: here is a different way of categorizing philosophy that someone who clearly spends a great deal of time within its works.  In addition to your original search for schools of thought, you may also want to try exploring in this direction as well!  You never know where it might lead!

Comment: Ryder, a school of thought, for example would be Platonism, Neo-Platonism, Stoicism, Nihilism. What you've enumerated are subdisciplines of philosophy. Stoicism makes claims about ethics, epistemology, metaphysics, and so on that differ in some ways and agree in others from diffferent schools.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery thanks for the clarification. Still not sure a "list" of schools like that exists, though it might be interesting ... but very, very, very long. What *doesn't* count as a school of thought? Objectivism? Libertarianism? It would make a terrific thesis, but it's far too broad a question for a .SE. You could do a decent job with `grep -e 'ism$'` on the full list of Routledge Encyclopedia entries, *maybe*, but this still misses out on evaluating the tree of "fundamentals" there are.